# How to set a palette to avoid stretching to a high value

Tags: gnuplot, palette, color-palette

I am plotting a pm3d map and using a colour palette.  However when using the colour palette I'm finding that stretching to a couple of high values causes the palettes colour to spread, so that differences in the plot cant be identified and is practically nearly one colour.

The data is mostly distributed to the lower end of the palette with a couple of high values.

I'm wondering if there is any solution to this? Maybe specifying a colour palette to the majority of the distributed data and a single colour from there onwards up?

Comment: You could use a fixed upper limit for the color range as e.g. `set cbrange [*:10]`. Then you could overwrite the `10` tic with `>10` as `set cbtics add ('> 10' 10)`.

Comment: Ok, would that adjust the image tho?

Comment: This isn't a bad option actually, I used it and its good.  Its a shame tho I cant adjust the colour palette from 10 to the max with a solid colour.

Comment: Well, you could do it, but I don't think its better: `set palette defined (0 'red', 1 'blue', 1000 'blue')`.

Comment: Um, i dont think its possible to set from 10 to the max value using a constant colour using this method.  I might use your original method.

Comment: You can get the max of the data using `stats 'datafile'`, then the max will be in the variable `STATS_*max` (the asterisk is because I am not sure how your data is formatted; type `show variables all` to see what it is called).